# Sqlanywehere 16, show the result of row Po_Order only once

Tags: sqlanywhere

I need that the result of Po_Order just show in the first line.

```
SELECT
DBA.sky_listactes.NroCteSequencial AS PO_Order, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.Qtd, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.Peso, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.NotaFiscal,
DBA.sky_listactes.LoteTransmissao 
FROM DBA.sky_listactes
INNER JOIN 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias ON DBA.sky_listactes.Id = 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.CteId
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1Iqc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
If number() = 1 then DBA.sky_listactes.NroCteSequencial Else NULL End If AS 
PO_Order, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.Qtd, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.Peso, 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.NotaFiscal,
DBA.sky_listactes.LoteTransmissao 
FROM DBA.sky_listactes
INNER JOIN 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias ON DBA.sky_listactes.Id = 
DBA.sky_listctemercadorias.CteId
```